# Agrupar un array de diccionarios por un valor de la Key

Tags: python, flask

A través de un bucle for estoy obteniendo un array con diccionarios de datos de coches, adjunto ejemplo:

```
[
        {
            'categoria':'A',
            'vehiculo':'Opel Astra',
            'cc':'1.6',
            'combustible':'gasolina'
        },
        {
            'categoria':'A',
            'vehiculo':'xxxxx',
            'cc':'xxxx',
            'combustible':'xxxxx'
        },
        {
            'categoria':'B',
            'vehiculo':'Seat Leon',
            'cc':'xxxx',
            'combustible':'xxxxx'
        },
        {
            'categoria':'B',
            'vehiculo':'Audi A3',
            'cc':'xxxx',
            'combustible':'xxxxx'
        },
        {
            'categoria':'C',
            'vehiculo':'Ford Fiesta',
            'cc':'xxxx',
            'combustible':'xxxxx'
        },
        {
            'categoria':'C',
            'vehiculo':'Nissan Micra',
            'cc':'xxxx',
            'combustible':'xxxxx'
        },
]
```

Me gustaría generar un nuevo array de diccionarios agrupando todos los coches de categoría A en un diccionario, todos los coches de categoría B en otro diccionario y así sucesivamente: por ejemplo

"A" {
'vehiculo':'Opel Astra',
'cc':'1.6',
'combustible':'gasolina'
},
{
'vehiculo':'Nissan Micra',
'cc':'xxxx',
'combustible':'xxxxx'
}

"B" {
'vehiculo':'Seat Leon',
'cc':'1.6',
'combustible':'gasolina'
},
{
'vehiculo':'Audi A3',
'cc':'xxxx',
'combustible':'xxxxx'
}

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando el módulo `itertools` es muy fácil de lograrlo gracias a la función `groupby` que nos permite agrupar un iterable en base a un elemento.

```py
grupos = {}
for cat, group in groupby(diccionario, key=lambda x: x["categoria"]):
    grupos[cat]= list(group)
```

La variable `cat` contiene la categoría y `group` tiene todos los elementos que agrupados con esa categoría.